# Multiple Macro Keyboards of the same brand affect each other?

Tags: keyboard, macros

I have a Redragon Kala (That is like [Redragon Kama](https://redragonusa.com/products/keyboard/K578-BRRGB%20-%20%20KAMA/148) but with "Ç" and minor design changes) and it comes with a software where I can customize any of the keys to do other commands and macros.

I am considering getting a [Redragon DITI](https://www.redragonzone.com/collections/keyboard/products/redragon-k585-keyboard) that I am considering getting. While this already has 7 dedicated macro keys, I wanted to be able to customize it completely.

Since both keyboards have the letter "Q" on them, if I configure my DITI, will it affect my Kala?

Comment: Yes, probably.....

Comment: I am on the probably side too, but since the software even pulls the correct Keyboard image, I wonder if they do some kind of writing on the keyboard itself

Comment: I use Logitech, so it might not be true for your case. For my case I can customize my tools independently.

Comment: Multiple logitech keyboards? I use a mouse (with like 16 keys on the side) and a keyboard, both from redragon and they work independently